# How to create a equality operator for a class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have this data type and I want to define a equality operator for it. Mlist should be an instance of Eq.

```
data Mlist a = Mlist [a]

instance Eq a => Eq (Mlist a) where
    (==) :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

The equality operator should allow me to check this (plus the ordering shouldn't matter):

```
m1 = Mlist [1,2,3]
m2 = Mlist [3,1,2]
-- then m1 equals m2
m3 = Mlist [3,2,1,5]
-- then m1 not equals m3
```

The top code isn't working, can anyone help with this?

Edit:
Here is a new version, but it's not working...

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Mlist a) where
    (==) :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
    (==) [] [] = True
    (==) [] _ = False
    (==) _ [] = False
    (==) (hd:tl) b = (==) tl $ delete hd b
```

Comment: You need to define `(==) :: Eq a => Mlist a -> Mlist a -> Bool`, but not `(==) :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`.

Comment: You sure you don't want to use `Data.Set`?

Answer (score 9):

To make `Mlist a` an instance of `Eq`, you have to define either

```
(==) :: Mlist a -> Mlist a -> Bool
```

or

```
(/=) :: Mlist a -> Mlist a -> Bool
```

In essence, you need to implement a function which can determine whether two lists equal. Since `Eq` is the only constraint, you can use the help from [`Data.List.\\`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3a-92--92-). For example:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Mlist a) where
    Mlist xs == Mlist ys = length xs ==  length ys && null (xs \\ ys)
```

Comment: Didn't know about the \\. Nice :)

Answer (score 0):

To address your edit: the new version does not work because instance declarations should not have type signatures. The type signature is given by the class.

The code is still incorrect, because you haven't accounted for the case where `hd` is not in `b`. In that case, `delete hd b` is just `b`, so in particular if `tl == b` then you'll return `True`, when you really should have returned `False`.